# Using React's Fetch Method: Chrome Dev Tools Shows Two Responses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, httprequest, google-chrome-devtools

We're working on a project for class and sending a POST request to our server. We should get back an API token. We console.log it and it shows a different (unwanted) response in the console, but in the network tab it shows the correct response is being sent back.

Why is this happening? Even if we are getting back a bad response, you would think it would be the same in both places.

I'll try to update with an example of the code when I can, just wondering if anyone has ran into a similar issue.

```
//  Response in Console:
//    { type: "cors", url: "someurl", status: "200", ok: true, statusText: "OK"}
//
//  Response in Network > Name > Response
//  {"user":{"id": xxx, "username": xxxxx}, "apiToken": xxxx}
//
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that you use to send the request? What fetch method are you referring to exactly?

Comment: share both your request/response headers, most likely is to do with CORS or incorrect headers

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a more recent build? [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) is essentially a nightly build, it has the latest fixes in for testing. Issues like this are known due to the `x-devtools-emulate-network-conditions` header sent with requests. It has been fixed in the latest builds but as it only affects pages when DevTools is open, it won't be patched into the current Stable release since it isn't affecting general browsing.